# Airflow - import DAGs from multiple repositories

Tags: python, git, airflow

We have deployed airflow using the official helm chart on kubernetes, we are using KubernetesExecutor and git-sync.

I have no problems running DAGs from a single Gitlab repository, however how are you supposed to load DAGs from a different repository? I ran into this discussion - https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/19381#discussioncomment-4976747, which suggests using git submodules. Fair enough, however I struggle designing a proper repository structure.

I have a base airflow repo, which I would like to have some common DAGs, plugins and tests. Then I would add other repos to this base one using git submodules. The structure I came up with looks like this

```
.
├── dags/
│   ├── common/
│   │   ├── common_dag_1.py
│   │   ├── common_dag_2.py
│   │   └── util/
│   │       └── util_code_dag_1.py
│   └── added_repo_1/
│       ├── added_dag_1
│       ├── added_dag_2
│       └── util/
│           └── util_code_added_dag_1.py
├── plugins/
│   ├── hooks/
│   ├── sensors/
│   └── operators/
└── tests/
```

Now a couple of questions

- A lot of our `added_repo`s currently have a lot of custom code like jupyter notebooks, sometimes it's already a python package or contains random eval scripts. Should we split or restructure them, to have only the relevant code in it?
- What about tests of the `added_repo`s? I assume they should be run using CI/CD pipelines at their original location, what should be put in the base repo tests?
- Any other tips how to improve the overall project structure?

Comment: could you tell why do you need to use several repositories and not 1?